# Need to call methods in other viewControllers from another viewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have an app that has multiple viewControllers, where some of these viewControllers contain methods that run various tasks.  What I need to do is when the initial viewController loads, is to call these methods in the other viewControllers such that they run in the background, however, I am having some difficulty doing this.

Let's say I have 4 viewControllers, A, B, C, & D, where A is the initial viewController, and in each viewController, I have aMethod, bMethod, cMethod, and dMethod respectively.  Here is the relevant code:

Inside my opening viewController (AviewController):

in the .h file:

```
#import "BViewController"
#import "CViewController"
#import "DViewController"

@interface AViewController:UIViewController {

BViewController *bViewCon;
CViewController *cViewCon;
DViewController *dViewCon;


}

@property (nonatomic, retain) BViewController *bViewCon;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CViewController *cViewCon;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DViewController *dViewCon;

@end
```

In my .m file I have the following:

```
#import "BViewController"
#import "CViewController"
#import "DViewController"

@implementation AviewController

@synthesize bViewCon, cViewCon, dViewCon;

- (void) viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

bViewCon = [[BViewController alloc] init];
[bViewCon bMethod];

...

}
```

However, I am getting the error message, "No visible @interface for 'BViewController' declares the selector 'bMethod'".  I need to call the other methods from the other viewControllers the same way from this class (i.e. AViewController).

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Comment: Be careful creating all of these view controllers initially like you're doing... `UIViewController` isn't exactly cheap in terms of memory usage... have you considered perhaps creating a single manager controller (subclass of `NSObject` instead, which is cheaper) to handle all of said background taks?

Comment: Unfortunately no, and at this point it is too late to go back and redesign the app.

Comment: Sounds to me like you might need to consider refactoring.

Comment: It's a secret answer. You shouldn't need to call methods in your other viewcontrollers. You should definately redesign the application, as this problem will sooner or later catch up with you, and it will be even harder to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the error you're receiving, make sure that all of the methods are declared in the header (.h) files of each controller (otherwise, the compiler won't be able to see them).

As all of these controllers are children to `AViewController` (they are created by `AViewController` and kept as ivars on it), I wouldn't use `NSNotificationCenter` here (unless there are other objects that need to be notified in case of certain events occurring too, which aren't owned by `AViewController`).

Instead, I would just call the methods directly as you're attempting to do.

On another note, if these methods are starting ongoing tasks (running tasks in background), it may be best for you to move the method calls to the `init:` method of `AViewController`. (As on iOS 5, views CAN be unloaded and hence `viewDidLoad:` can be called potentially more than once... such as in the case of memory warnings and the view being off screened). I might go about doing something like this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:bundle];  // your correct stuff here
    if (self)
    {
         bViewCon = [[BViewController alloc] init];
         [bViewCon bMethod];
         // ... and so on for the other controllers
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Edit**

Although, as mentioned in a comment, `UIViewController`s aren't exactly cheap in terms of memory... it honestly would likely be best to refactor this code to have a single controller (a subclass of `NSObject` instead of `UIViewController`, which is cheaper) to act as a manager for the tasks that are going to be running in the background. I imagine this will likely help you later down the road too, as it would help compartmentalize the tasks and purpose of each of your controllers (in such, `UIViewController`s should primarily be responsible for managing a view (/view hierarchy in some cases) and associated tasks... if there are ongoing tasks that are occurring outside the scope of things associated with said view, it's probably a sign that the `UIViewController` shouldn't be handling them...

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered using `NSNotificationCenter`? Set up the methods on the notifications and just ping them when you need them to run. This helps if your other view controller is instantiated and available, like buried in the navigation controller stack or on a separate tab.

To answer you question about that error, you need to declare the method you want to call in your header file. The error is stating it can't find a declaration for that method.

Example of notification center

```
// listen for notifications - add to view controller doing the actions
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mySpecialMethod) name:@"SomeNotificationName" object:nil];

// when you want your other view controller to do something, post a notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SomeNotificationName" object:nil];

// you don't want this notification hanging around, so add this when you are done or in dealloc/viewDidUnload
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]; // this removes all notifications for this view
// if you want to remove just the one you created, you can remove it by name as well
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply.  I have never used NSNotificationCenter, can you show me how with an example please?

Comment: Is there a way around using NSNotificationCenter and calling the methods directly the way I have shown above?

Comment: Have you put the method signature in the viewcontroller's .h file? E.G. in  BViewController.h do you have a line that says "-(void)bMethod;" where void is replaced with whatever the function returns. Those signatures is how you can make other classes aware of what a class can do.

Comment: I don't think `NSNotificationCenter` is entirely appropriate here... the main reason is that each of these `UIViewController`s is a child to `AViewController`, so it makes more sense for `AViewController` to just call the methods directly on its children, in my opinion.

Comment: Agreed. The issue is the methods are not defined. If it is a matter of just performing the methods, yes, just call them directly. If there is data saved in those views and you don't want to reinitialize, notifications work. They are easy and usually do the trick.

Comment: Perfect Nice and clear understanding of NSNotificationCenter +1 for the detailed explanations :)