# What is the difference between UILocalnotification and delegates?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, delegates, uilocalnotification

I have an application in which i want to get notified whether the method is called or not from other class. So, i am a bit confused whether to use `UILocalnotification` or create a delegate method using `protocol`. Anyone please help me.

Comment: in your case you have to use `protocol`

Comment: i don't know why people marking negative. Please don't do that.

Comment: People don't mark negative when the question actually shows some research effort, or in general adheres to [the standards required for questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use either `delegate/ protocol` or `NSNotificationCenter`. You cannot use UILocalnotification it is used for different purpose.

> Instances of UILocalNotification represent notifications that an application can schedule for presentation to its users at specific dates and times. The operating system is responsible for delivering the notification at the proper time

That means UILocalNotification is used to notify the user of your application not for your custom class objects. It will appear as alert if the app is in background.

If you just want to get notified for some changes use [**NSNotificationCenter**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It will solve your problem no need of delegate here.
Here is tutorial
[NSNotificationCenter Tutorial](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/16/nsnotificationcenter-tutorial-using-the-notification-center-in-your-iphone-app/)

Comment: Can you please explain UILocalnotification is for which purpose?

Answer (score 1):

`Delegation` means that the another object is called to perform a specific task,
Like your friend going to purchase 2 movie tickets - you have a say where to go, which show, what movie , invite more friends.and it is like you call your friend and say something and also getting response from your friend tell until you hang up the phone

`Notification` happens only after the task has been performed, 
and the notified object can not change the event anymore. 
Like your friend txt you "I have 2 tickets for movie, would you like to come?".and the Notification is just like the Radio station, broadcast your message and you do't know who is listening or not.

this is what i read somewhere one of the finest difference i found on SO.

Answer (score 0):

**What is UILocalNotification?**

`UILocalNotifications` are only displayed automatically if the app is not running (or running in background). If the app is running and a local notification fires, UIApplicationDelegate’s `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` method gets called and the system doesn’t display anything (nor does it play a sound). If you want to display the notification, create an UIAlertView yourself in the delegate method.

**What is Delegates?**

Delegation as I understand it is when an object will pass the responsibility of handeling an event to another object thus "delegating" the responsibility to that object.

For example if you have an NSButton in iOs you generally assign the Delegate to be the parent view controller. This means instead of handeling touchUp events in the definition of the button it is instead handled in the view controller.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i want to know, just the basic difference between the two. The both can be called if the app is in background.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `#import<Appdelegate.h>` file on which class where you call that method.

if your method is declared in AppDelegate then you have to create the shared instance of AppDelegate like this

```
AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

and called required method like below code.

`[self delegate.getData];`    // getdata is function write here your function.

i hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want how to call it from another class then you should go for:-

[Need to call methods in other viewControllers from another viewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130334/need-to-call-methods-in-other-viewcontrollers-from-another-viewcontroller)

Now come to `UILocalNotification`. It's mainly used when we don't know whenever a local event will trigger out so that we can perform that action which required in your programming at that time. It will also shown when application is in background.

delegation is predefined communication which handled from programming or may be call at the time of running. So for `protocol` (custom delegation) or delegation you should be know previously which one is called and scheduled it so.

In your case you should use `UILocalNotification` which is part of Notification's and apart from it you can go for `KVO` .[(Key Value observation)](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html&ei=c-ORUdG6EonOrQf71IGoDQ&usg=AFQjCNGGbZPY7RkF0X1h0HIkcYg7s1Pseg&sig2=uxde182Wyd7MnhWHtUXA3Q&bvm=bv.46471029,d.bmk)